# ubuntu system diagnostics

Tags: error-handling, diagnostic

I keep getting errors "sorry, Ubuntu 16.04 has experienced an internal error" giving me the option to report error. I generally leave that checked. Is there any type of system diagnostics that I can run to determine what the problem is and stop these messages from annoying me?

```
james@tablet:~$ ls -al /var/crash/
total 22908
drwxrwsrwt  2 root     whoopsie     4096 Aug 15 07:35 .
drwxr-xr-x 15 root     root         4096 Aug  4 00:46 ..
-rw-r-----  1 james    whoopsie 23446740 Aug 14 03:14 _opt_MessengerForDesktop_Messenger.1000.crash
-rw-rw-r--  1 james    whoopsie        0 Aug 14 03:15 _opt_MessengerForDesktop_Messenger.1000.upload
-rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie        0 Aug 14 03:15 _opt_MessengerForDesktop_Messenger.1000.uploaded
```

Comment: As a start, simply expand the *Details* section and see what package caused the problem. Most other data there is probably only relevant for developers though...

Comment: What is the output of `ls -al /var/crash/` ?

Comment: @Raphael sorry for taking so long to reply.  Here's the output: http://hastebin.com/uniciqucew.hs